# how to solve power surge problem?

Tags: switches

I am currently working on dc/dc converter. The converter needs to power up a computer monitor. however after powering up i observed some wavy lines on monitor along with a power surge pop up. can anyone tell me the reason behind this and how to solve?

Comment: Could You provide more information about the project?
What is the converter topology, controller, Provide some schematics or layout.
Often this kind of disturbances are causes by wrong values of Output Capacitor or the Coil.

Comment: I am using a step down converter. controller is a TI based LM5088. The filter capacitor that we are using are 22uf(2 nos) and one 330uf aluminium electrolyte. we used an evaluation board made from TI.

Comment: @akky: Welcome to EE.SE. All that information along with a schematic and a link to datasheet should be in the question, not scattered through the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Verify the output voltage, check if You have any high frequency compund variable from switching.

If so, try using higher values of LC filter or even try to apply additional LC output filer or Ferrite in series.

I would also try to use different swithcing frequency, maybe You hit the screen clock freuqncy by one of the harmonics coming from SMPS.